# Didselectrow not getting called after deleting a row inside the commitEditingStyle method after clicking on the navigation rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After I delete a row inside commitEditingStyle method the didSelectRow delegate is not getting called in a UITableViewController class. I need the solution for swift.

Note: I have used self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem() and have also overriden the setEditing method.

I am terribly stuck. Please help.

Comment: Why would `didSelectRow` be called? You're deleting a row not selecting it. :)

Comment: I meant that the deletion of that row is successfully done but after the table gets refreshed I cannot select any other rows anymore.

Comment: Do you have a `delegate` set up on table view?

Comment: ofcource..before deleting the row every delegate was working fine

Comment: Make sure you are also concluding the edit mode. Otherwise you have to set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property of `UITableView` to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks man !!!...That was what I missing...great !!